# Kafka Partitioner using value instead of key

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm having a special case where I would need to make sure that all messages for a `parent` key go to a specific partition. Assuming following attributes for the key

- `pk` : `UUID`

and for the value

- `parent` : `String`
- `name` : `String`
- `familyName` : `String`
- etc.

Previously I've implemented other partitioners but I always was able to take the relevant information from the key part. The interface [org.apache.kafka.clients.producerPartitioner](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Partitioner.html) shows for the method partition both possibilities key and value. However it also denotes that all of them could be null.

I'm asking this because the content of the stream later also gets loaded into a materialized view. This view should allow to search for the "pk".
If I would include the `parent` attribute in the key as well, I could no longer search for a `pk` unless I'd have `parent` as well.

Here is how I setup a materialized view inside of a stream processing topology:

```
KTable<MyObjectKey, MyObjectValue> myObjects = builder
  .table("topicName", Consumed.with(myObjectKeySerde, myObjectValueSerde),
         Materialized.<MyObjectKey, MyObjectValue, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("viewName")
           .withKeySerde(myObjectKeySerde)
           .withValueSerde(myObjectValueSerde));
```

Later I then can access it like

```
final MyObjectKey pk = MyObjectKey.newBuilder().setUUID(... UUID searched for).build();
final ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<MyObjectKey, MyObjectValue> store =
  streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getKafkaStreams()
    .store( fromNameAndType("viewName", keyValueStore()));
MyObjectValue value = store.get(pk);
```

In theory could use a range query which then would allow me to include `parent` in the key. Such I then would search from `pk`+ `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` to `pk`+ `ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff`.

Comment: "Could be" null, but you are in full control of your own producers, so you decide what actually will be null... I don't think the key and value can be null at the same time. But please clarify what you mean by "materialized view"... You should be able to do prefix searches by a UUID or string

Comment: Thanks for swift reply! I've updated original question now showing examples on how to create materialized view as well as how to search.

Comment: What is wrong with [`prefixScan`](https://kafka.apache.org/32/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/ReadOnlyKeyValueStore.html#prefixScan(P,PS))? Then you can get data from all `pk`, then you can further filter from that result

Comment: There is always something to learn from you! Awesome, never looked into prefixScan. Will definitely need check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> make sure that all messages for a parent key go to a specific partition

A `Partitioner` would be the correct way to do that.

> method partition both possibilities key and value. However it also denotes that all of them could be null

If you have full control over the producers using the Partitioner, that shouldn't be an issue. I don't think both key and value can be null, at least not with a state-store where non-null keys are required.

---

If you build the keys such as simple strings `parent:pk`, then use [`ReadOnlyKeyValueStore#prefixScan`](https://kafka.apache.org/32/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/ReadOnlyKeyValueStore.html#prefixScan(P,PS)), that should allow you to get all data for a particular parent prefix, after which, you'd need to check the values of the returned iterator for any more filtering / lookups.